# Grid Game Wrong Solution C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to brute force my way through the Grid Game problem on LeetCode without knowing what prefix sum was. And I thought my solution was good, not optimal but should get the job done. However, it failed on the 9th test case in a way that I don't understand.

Testcase

```
using solutions;

int[][] testCase = new int [2][];

testCase[0] = new int[] {20,3,20,17,2,12,15,17,4,15};
testCase[1] = new int[] {20,10,13,14,15,5,2,3,14,3};

SolutionV2 SLN = new SolutionV2();
Console.WriteLine(SLN.GridGame(testCase));
```

My Solution

```
namespace solutions;
public class SolutionV2 {
    public long GridGame(int[][] grid) 
    {
        long returnValue = 0;
        long maxValue = 0;
        int[] currentPosition = new int[] {0,0};
        int maxCol = grid[0].GetLength(0);
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", grid[0]));
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", grid[1]));

        for(int k=0;k<maxCol;k++) //find the highest path sum for the first robot
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<maxCol;i++) 
            {
                if(i<k)
                { 
                    sum += grid[0][i]; //sum up the first row until it is time to move down
                }
                else if(i==k)
                {
                    sum += grid[0][i];
                    for(int j=i;j<maxCol;j++)
                    {
                        sum += grid[1][j];
                    }
                    if(sum>maxValue)
                    {
                        maxValue = sum;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int k=0;k<maxCol;k++) //there has to be a better way to set the sum path to zero
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<maxCol;i++) 
            {
                if(i<k)
                { 
                    sum += grid[0][i]; //sum up the first row until it is time to move down
                }
                else if(i==k)
                {
                    sum += grid[0][i];
                    for(int j=i;j<maxCol;j++)
                    {
                        sum += grid[1][j];
                    }
                    if(sum==maxValue) //found it, now set the path to zero
                    {
                        for(int a=0;a<=i;a++)
                        {
                            grid[0][a] = 0;
                        }
                        for(int a=i;a<maxCol;a++)
                        {
                            grid[1][a] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", grid[0]));
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", grid[1]));

        for(int k=0;k<maxCol;k++) //find the highest path sum for the second robot
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<maxCol;i++) 
            {
                if(i<k)
                { 
                    sum += grid[0][i]; //sum up the first row until it is time to move down
                }
                else if(i==k)
                {
                    sum += grid[0][i];
                    for(int j=i;j<maxCol;j++)
                    {
                        sum += grid[1][j];
                    }
                    if(sum>returnValue)
                    {
                        returnValue = sum;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

The expected value for this particular test case was 63, which I don't understand where they got it from.

Comment: "_The expected value for this particular test case was 63, which I don't understand where they got it from._" Isn't that explained on https://leetcode.com/problems/grid-game/ ? If i misunderstood what you said, what would you believe the expected value is?

Comment: Well, i just did a (naive) implementation of the game as described at  https://leetcode.com/problems/grid-game/ with your grid data just for fun, and i get 63: https://dotnetfiddle.net/va7Oju (My apologies, but i won't explain that code. For what's worth that code has to speak for itself. And since it's dirty and quickly cobbled together, i don't like to explain why i did the terrible dirty things i did there...)

Comment: According to my understanding, the best move for the first robot to get the highest score was to move all the way to the right and then down, resulting in (20+3+20+17+2+12+15+17+4+15+3) = 128 and those fields being set to 0. Then when it comes to the second robot turn, its best move is to go down and then all the way to the right, resulting in (20+10+13+14+15+5+2+3+14) = 96 points, which is a whole lot higher than the expected value, which made me wonder if I am not understanding some nuance of the rules.

Comment: "_for the first robot to get the highest score_" Where in the rules does it say that the red/first robot wants to get the highest score? ;-)